# Print in file the lexical errors ANTLR intelliJ

Tags: java, antlr

I tryed to print in a file the lexical errors from a simple input, I already define my grammar and all is ok, my main is this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CharStream charStreamES1 = CharStreams.fromString("{ int ]a; int b; àint c = 1 ; if (c > 1) { b = c  } else { a = b ; }}");
        SimpLanPlusLexer simpleLexer = new SimpLanPlusLexer(charStreamES1);
        SimpLanPlusParser simpleparser = new SimpLanPlusParser(new CommonTokenStream(simpleLexer));
        simpleLexer.removeErrorListeners();
        SyntaxErrorListener act = new SyntaxErrorListener();
        RecognitionException a = null;
        act.syntaxError(simpleparser,0,0,0,"msg",a);
    }
}
```

In the CharStream there are different error like "]" or "à"
I had Override the syntaxError function like this:

```
public class SyntaxErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {
    private final List<SyntaxError> SyntaxErrors = new ArrayList();

    public SyntaxErrorListener() {
    }

    List<SyntaxError> getSyntaxErrors() {
        return this.SyntaxErrors;
    }

    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        this.SyntaxErrors.add(new SyntaxError(recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, charPositionInLine, msg, e));

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Myerrors.txt");
            Iterator var8 = this.getSyntaxErrors().iterator();

            while(var8.hasNext()) {
                SyntaxError i = (SyntaxError)var8.next();
                out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
                System.out.println(i.getMessage());
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException var10) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my SyntaxError class:

```
public class SyntaxError {
    private final Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer;
    private final Object offendingSymbol;
    private final int line;
    private final int charPositionInLine;
    private final String msg;
    private final RecognitionException e;

    public SyntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        this.recognizer = recognizer;
        this.offendingSymbol = offendingSymbol;
        this.line = line;
        this.charPositionInLine = charPositionInLine;
        this.msg = msg;
        this.e = e;
    }
```

under this I had already defined the get function of my parameters that I did't rite in this questio, can anybody help me pls?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: My code doesn't print the error, the follow instructions doesn't works:

out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
System.out.println(i.getMessage());

Answer (score 0):

You’ve used `simpleLexer.removeErrorListeners();` to remove the default error listener, but you have not added your error listener(`act`) to the `simpleLexer`.

Also, a listener on `simpleLexer` will only pick up Tokenization errors (invalid tokens).  You’ll also want to add you listener to your parser.

BTW, both Lexers and Parsers can have multiple listeners, so it’s not *necessary* to remove the default listeners.  If you want to remove them to clean up the `System.out`, you may want to keep them connected until you have verified that you’re listeners are hooked up and functioning correctly, as they may give some insight.